# Koltin, setting a mediaplayer from a variable

Tags: android, kotlin, mp3, raw

I'm working on an application, where for specific choosen items, specific .mp3 should be assigned. (Like I choose Dachshund, then I dachshund_1.mp3, dachshund_2.mp3 etc. to be played when my functions say so). Is it possible somehow, that I create a variable, that holds the specific name, then I assign it to mediaplayer.create?

What I would like to do would look like that below:

> ```
> // I have a function here that returns with the specific string
> // I have a cnt variable in the code which helps determine which text and sound comes now
> ```

```
fun DogHandler(cnt:Int, receiptName: String) :String
{
   return dogName + "_" +cnt.toString()
}
```

> This function is called, and the string it returns should go to the mediaplayer. Cnt is let's say 10

```
var tmp = DogHandler(dachshund, cnt);     // tmp = dachsund_10
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.tmp)
mediaPlayer.start()
```

Comment: I am struggling to understand your question. I see you have a method `DogHandler` to generate the names, but where are the MP3 ? Do you have files `dachsund_0` to `dachsund_10` in `raw` in you Android project?

Comment: That's exactly the case, they're in raw folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no way to generate resource IDs (like `R.raw.something`) dynamically. However, you could simply create a list of them and access it by index.

```kotlin
val dachsunds = listOf(
    R.raw.dachsund_0,
    R.raw.dachsund_1,
    R.raw.dachsund_2,
    R.raw.dachsund_3,
    // ...
    R.raw.dachsund_10
)

val dachsund = dachsunds[dachsundIndex]
val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, dachsund).apply {
    start()
}
```

Comment: That's a clever way to do! Seems perfect, gonna try it in the evening, thank you!